# Get all posts with all comments in json format

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

I have two models Post and Comment

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments
end

class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :post
end
```

How can I get all the posts with comments as below json response:

```
{
  "posts": [
    {
      "name": "Ruby on Rails",
      "comments": [
        {
          "desc": "awesome"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "Java",
      "comments": [
        {
          "desc": "Thanks"
        },
        {
          "desc": "very useful"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: You need to build a route and a controller for starters

Comment: pls add some code which you tried? and we will give you a way to achieve your requirement.

Comment: @max I have added a route `get 'posts', to: 'posts#index'` and created a post controller

Comment: Don't tell me. Edit your question to show what you have tried so far and exactly what did not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this, create a index.json.jbuilder in app/views/posts/  ,
and add the following code to it

```
json.posts @posts do |post|
  json.name post.name
  json.comments post.comments do |comment|
    json.desc comment.desc
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Use activemodel [Activemodel Serializers](https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers).Also check out this railscasts video which gives you a pretty good idea about activemodel serializers and how to use it [Railscasts-activemodel serializers](http://railscasts.com/episodes/409-active-model-serializers).
Hope i've helped.